# mongodb schema design for storing mysql column like array value query

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database-design, database-migration

I've mysql database who looks like this :

```
    ----|-----------|--------|------------|---------|----------|---------|----------|----------|
   _id| Segment_ID| Origin | Destination| Aircraft| Latitude1|Latitude2|Longitude1|Longitude2|
    ----|-----------|--------|------------|---------|----------|---------|----------|----------|
     1  | LFAQ-GILTO| LFAQ   | KURIS      | A3ST    | 49.56    | 2.5     | 49.97    | 2.33     |
    ----|-----------|--------|------------|---------|----------|---------|----------|----------|
   1    |GILTO-EVX  | LFAQ   | KURIS      | A3ST    | 49.97    | 2.33    | 50.70    | 2.12     |
    ----|-----------|--------|------------|---------|----------|---------|----------|----------|
    1   |EVX-KURIS  | LFAQ   | KURIS      | A3ST    | 50.70    | 2.12    | 52.00    | 2.07     |
    ----|-----------|--------|------------|---------|----------|---------|----------|----------|
```

i want to migrate my database from mysql to mongodb. i use mongify to migrate my database in embedded collection in mongodb. i had no problems with that. BUT, i want to do the next:
1. migrate to embedded collection in mongodb and put the columns as the array value.
2. i want my mongodb collection look like this

```
Flight: { 
  id:1 {
  "Segment_ID": "LFAQ-GILTO, GILTO-EVX, EVX-KURIS",
  "Origin": "LFAQ, LFAQ, LFAQ",  
  "Destination": "KURIS, KURIS, KURIS",
  "Aircraft" : "A3ST, A3ST, A3ST",
  "Latitude1" : "49.56, 49.97, 50.70",
etc.....
```

Is there any way i can make it work?

for now my database looks like:

```
Flight: {
id1: {
"0": {
"Segment_ID": "LFAQ-GILTO",
"Origin": "LFAQ",
"Destination": KURIS",
"Aircraft" : "A3ST",
"LAtitude1": "49.56",
.......
},
"1": {
"Segment_ID": "LFAQ-GILTO",
"Origin": "LFAQ",
"Destination": KURIS",
"Aircraft" : "A3ST",
"LAtitude1": "49.56",
.....
},
"2": {
"Segment_ID": "LFAQ-GILTO",
"Origin": "LFAQ",
"Destination": KURIS",
"Aircraft" : "A3ST",
"LAtitude1": "49.56",
.....},
......
```

Comment: What does the data look like in Mongo now? What have you tried? It looks very straightforward to convert to your desired structure, although it does look like you might have an unbounded amount of data in your document. Docs are limited to 16MB.

Comment: Why do you want your data to look that way? That looks awful to parse and work with...

Comment: my collegues who will work with this database asked me if i can design it that way, they thought it will work faster

Comment: @WiredPrairie could you show me please an exemple of query to use to structure the tables, i figured out how to export the data and import it directly to mongo with php, but i cant write the code to structure the table

Answer (score 1):

Your MongoDB structure is good to look when compare to MySql. But if you are keep the information like this, you have to do loop on reading data. If data size grow large, this loops will slow down your application.

For example,
You want rows where "Segment_ID" is "GILTO-EVX", In MongoDB, you have loop data against "Segment_ID" array. Because MongoDB is return Parent Key and all of its values, even single value match with your condition. In above case, MongoDB will give you

```
{ "Segment_ID": ["LFAQ-GILTO", "GILTO-EVX", "EVX-KURIS", ....] } //If you are keep values in array
{ "Segment_ID": "LFAQ-GILTO, GILTO-EVX, EVX-KURIS, ....." } //If you are keep values as string with comma seperated
```

Both are difficult to use further process. I mean you have to keep bigger array or bigger string in your variable. This complex will increase, on reading respective information  on other Keys(column) with respective to **"Segment_ID = GILTO-EVX"**.
Here my suggestion is restructure your MongoDB docs as follows,

```
//Doc 1
{ 
  "Flight_id" : 1,
  "Segment_ID": "LFAQ-GILTO",
  "Origin": "LFAQ",  
  "Destination": "KURIS",
  "Aircraft" : "A3ST",
}
//Doc 2
{ 
  "Flight_id" : 1,
  "Segment_ID": "GILTO-EVX",
  "Origin": "LFAQ",  
  "Destination": "KURIS",
  "Aircraft" : "A3ST",
}
//Doc3 and more...
```

Comment: If they're not programmer tell them thanks but no thanks.  Remember if 9 women have 9 babies in 9 months, statistically on average it takes 1 month to make a baby right?

Comment: Alright, I'm accept it. MongoDB server is do less search to locate your data. But once you get result from MongoDB, the effort is comes to your web application and those effort degrade your app performance, some times it leads to app crash as well . The better option push those effort to MongoDB. So that, your app can put busy with deliver information, instead of generating those information.

Comment: okey, thanks you for your advices :) it's only one week i've started to wrok with mongodb so i really didnt know which schema design select to make queries work faster